# three.min.js:2 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D

Tags: javascript, three.js

i got error three.min.js:2 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D when try to run the 3D object.

```
  const loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

  loader.load("./model/Room.obj", function (object) {
    scene.add(object.scene);
    console.log(object);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  });
```

Comment: Try just `scene.add(object);`.

Comment: now it come like this app.js:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: loader is not defined
    at init (app.js:53)
    at app.js:59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```js
scene.add(object.scene);
```

just do this when using `OBJLoader`:

```
scene.add(object);
```

`OBJLoader` always returns an instance of `THREE.Group` which has no `scene` property.

Also notice that the various loaders in `three.js` return their results in slightly different ways. Meaning the code in the `onLoad()` callback is specific for the respective loader.